# External page - give it JS instructions?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, overflow, external

I'm interested in linking to or embedding an external page, scrolling to a specific point. Is this possible, or do cross-browser securities prevent it?

One workaround I've considered is creating the iframe within a div, giving the iframe a negative margin and then overflow:hidden; the container div.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution could be to use JavaScript to scroll the page. However, if the page you are embedding is on a different domain, you cannot access its content with JavaScript if it is in an iframe (due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)). However, if it is on the same domain as the host page, you should be able to access it using JavaScript and then scroll using the `window.scrollTo(x,y)` method or similar (see [this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scrollTo)).

Also, if the page you are embedding has a named anchor (`<a name="blah">`) or a block-level element with a specific id (`<div id="blah">`) at the point you want to scroll to, you can link to it or embed it by using a URL such as [http://example.com/page#*blah*](http://example.com/page#blah) and it will scroll to blah automatically. This is not under the same-origin policy, so you can do something like `<iframe src="http://example.com/page#blah"></iframe>` and the frame will automatically be scrolled to *blah*, even if it is not on the same domain as the host.

The "iframe with negative margin" solution you mentioned could work, but that might be hard to implement and would probably cause problems, especially if you want full cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Somehow I missed the lesson about anchor linking to any node with an ID. That's awesome.